# IGraphM does not load on first run

Tags: igraphm

I am using IGraphM to calculate some centralities in the project. But the IGraphM package never loads on the first run.
The following statements I used to load the package.

```
    ClearAll;
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
strm = OpenWrite["output.log"];
$Output = {strm};

    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     CellEvaluationFunction -> (ToExpression[#, StandardForm, 
         Function[Null, 
          Module[{aborted = $Aborted}, 
           Internal`WithLocalSettings[Null, 
            aborted = (ReleaseHold[Most[Hold[##]]]; Last[Hold[##]]), 
            AbortProtect[
             If[aborted === $Aborted, Print["Did cleanup"]; Abort[]]]]], 
          HoldAll]] &)];
    Needs["IGraphM`"]
    
    g = IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[capturedFromPSO]
    << IGraphM
    
    IGVersion[]
    
    Graph[GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"], 
      EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1]], VertexStyle -> Black] // 
     IGEdgeMap[ColorData[109], EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeColoring]
```

I get some error messages like the following:
[image]

How can I load the IGraphM package on the first run.

Comment: Hi Syed. I suspect the error might be in the rest of the code, not in IGraphM itself. For instance, it seems that you are calling the package twice (once with `Needs[]`, and then with `<<IGraphM\``, these are doing the same thing). What happens when you open a fresh kernel, and simply execute `<<IGraphM\``? If it is correctly installed, this should be enough to execute any IGraphM command.